# which if fastest? xhr with XML or an dynamically add an script file?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a file, "script.php", that prints data from a database, but i want to dynamically load and handle the data from the file in javascript.
Is it fastest to create a new script tag (the "script.php" has the content-type: text/javascript), like

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "script.php";
appendTheScriptToTheHead(blablabla);
```

with the data in an javascript array or to recieve the data in XML format through an XHR, like (the "script.php" has the content-type: text/xml)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","script.php",true);
xhr.onload = function(){
    xhr.responseXML;
}
xhr.send(null);
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Why the hell does script.php have content type text/javascript ?

Comment: Go the XHR way , you have better event based system with conditions telling u if it failed , whereas there will be no method to check for the above in the Script tag way. Also it allows you to handle the output in a much better way then script tag!

Comment: @Raynos good question thats what i am wondering , maybe he is just sending a JSON Object like say 

content = { "x":"blah" } ;

Comment: @Raynos: Because it needs to if it outputs Javascript. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @JOn , i support raynos's point i mean what is the point on loading a  document fragment via script tag using an evaluation of script instead of using a simple runtime ?

Comment: @Abhishek: You and Raynos are saying totally different things. As for what is the point, the OP's question is your answer. And why is XHR "simple" while a script tag is not?

Comment: @Jon . normalize your english please , i am not very good with english :( .. can u explain in lower level english ?

Comment: @Abhishek: The point is that e.g. it may be faster -- which is also what the OP is asking.

Comment: I think i am going to write a small benchmark w8 .. lets just see which indeed is faster

Comment: Another option, Is it a good idea to recive the data in JSON format through an XHR and use like, var dataFromDB = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

Comment: I am nearly done with my benchmark

Comment: And @eruducer . JSON is much much faster then XML as its native javascript

Answer (score 2):

-- UPDATED --- OPTIMIZED CODE ---

I did a small benchmark and here are the results

for 1000 iterations,

XML Object took 4270ms

A simple script tag addition took 4169ms;

A powerful XHR using Eval function gave 3206ms; // Fastest

For the reference here are the client and server side scripts .

Script 2.php

```
<?php

echo trim('
 var dunce = {
    menu : {
        id:1,
        gohan:"goku blah blah blah"
    }

 };

console.log(dunce.menu.id);  // yeah its still faster

iteration++;
if(iteration<1000){
ScriptTAG();
}else{
            console.log("Total time taken for "+iteration+"iterations is "+ (new 
                                Date().getTime()-start) );
}');


?>
```

Script.php [ the xml output ]

```
 <?php
   header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
   echo"<menu><id>1</id><gohan>Goku blah blah blah</gohan></menu>";
 ?>
```

Client file

```
var iteration = 0;
        // Use XHR
        var start ;
        // Use console for firing these
        function XHR() {
            if(iteration == 0) {
                start = new Date().getTime();
            }
            var io = new XMLHttpRequest();
            io.open("POST",'script.php',true);
            io.onload = function() {
                iteration++;
                if(iteration<1000) {
                    XHR();
                } else {
                    alert("Total time taken for "+iteration+"iterations is "+ (new Date().getTime()-start) );
                }
            }
            io.send();
        }
            function AlterXHR(){
            // EVAL IDEA

             if(iteration == 0){
                start = new Date().getTime();
            }
            var io = new XMLHttpRequest();
            io.open("POST",'script2.php',true);
            io.onload = function(){
                eval(io.responseText);
            }
            io.send();
            }
        function ScriptTAG() {
            if(iteration == 0 ) {
                start = new Date().getTime();
            }
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "script2.php";
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }

        ScriptTAG(); // Replace this with whatever u want to test! and run!!
```

I think the difference here was purely because of native javascript object's faster compilation over XML Parser .

As you can see the same script with NATIVE EVAL functionality worked way faster!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to send your database results through Ajax and better in JSON format, so they can be easily handled by some JavaScript function on the server side.

This option lets you have a fallback part in your code, in case something wrong happens.

Answer (score 0):

XML is always slow to consume in JavaScript, since you need to use a DOM-parser to read it, therefore JSON is always to prefere when using JavaScript.

Off topic:
You should note the security risk when offering your data to a dynamic script tag, as your site could be subject for some XSRF-attacks, because of the omitting same origin policy you get when using XHR.

Avoid this by adding a while(1); on the top of your response, making if impossible to consume your data with a script-tag from some evil site. This must of course be removed before you consuming the data.

Good luck :)